# What's the meaning of "utsname" in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, posix

In Linux, there is a header file called `<sys/utsname.h>`. And there is a utsname structure which shall contain members below:

- char  sysname[]  Name of this implementation of the operating system.
- char  nodename[] Name of this node within the communications 
               network to which this node is attached, if any.
- char  release[]  Current release level of this implementation.
- char  version[]  Current version level of this release.
- char  machine[]  Name of the hardware type on which the system is running.

I'm curious about the letter "**u**, **t**, **s**", what do they mean?

Comment: I'm not confident enough to post this as an answer, but from [*What's a UTS namespace?*](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183717/whats-a-uts-namespace): "UTS stands for UNIX Timesharing System"

Comment: UNIX Time Sharing or UNIX Timesharing System. Old relic

Comment: Thank you. I think you are right.

Comment: this should be more appropriate on [unix.se]

Answer (score 2):

I think it comes from the ancestor operating system where this syscall was already defined, so utsname means "Unix Time-Sharing System Name".

The full name for UNIX can be seen here:
http://cva.stanford.edu/classes/cs99s/papers/ritchie-thompson-unix-time-sharing-system.pdf